# Idiomatic means of choosing class constructor in groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a class like this:

in foo.groovy

```
class Foo {

    String thing
    Integer other

    Foo(String thing) {
        this.thing = thing
    }

    Foo(Integer other) {
        this.other = other
    }
}
return Foo.class
```

Now I would like to invoke these constructors. What I am doing is:

Other.groovy

```
def foo = evaluate(new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource('foo.groovy').file)).newInstance(10)
def foo2 = evaluate(new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource('foo.groovy').file)).newInstance("thing")
```

But this doesn't seem like the correct way of doing it. Ideally I would like to actually name the file `Foo.groovy` but then I get an error because it automatically declares the class for me. Basically, I want it to work like a classic Java class

Comment: Why are you returning the class in your scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but:

```
class Foo {      
    String thing     
    Integer other      

    Foo(String thing) {         
        this.thing = thing     
    }      
    Foo(Integer other) {         
        this.other = other     
    } 
}

def x = new Foo(10)
assert x.other == 10 // true

def y = new Foo("foo")
assert y​​​​.thing​ == "foo"​​ // true
```

What are you trying to accomplish here other than that?

Edit:  [Try it here](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/edit/5148659222052864).